# Filter Livetable Data using parameters

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql, ajax

I want to add some filtering options to filter table data.
Let say I want to filter table whose country is India based on the select option data from database and the table will only show data from country India.

```
<html>
<?php
$result = @pg_query("SELECT * FROM country order by country_name");

echo "<select name=\"country_name\" style=\"width: 180px;\" id=\"country_name\">
<option value=\"\">Select</option>";
while($row = pg_fetch_array($result))
{
$brg = $row['country_name'];
echo" <option value=\"$brg\">".$row['country_name']."</option>";
}
echo"</select>";

?>

</html>
```

and then filter from those indian country filtered the names i want to filter let say another option

```
<html>
<?php

<select>
<option>Arvind Jangir</option>
<option>Manish Jangir</option>

</select>

?>
</html>
```

This is the livetable i am using :
[HERE](http://demo.blogaddition.com/livetable/)

hope someone can help :) thanks

Comment: Do you want the filtering to be applied client-side or server-side? Do you want the first filter to be server-side and the second client-side?

Comment: could it be possible if the filtering can be done on the client side ? both first and second filter ? I am planning to filter up to the number of available fields.

Comment: I don't know if the plugin (link you provided) you are using has that funcionality. There are some ready solution about this. Google "searchable tables plugin" or just see this http://listjs.com/

Comment: i was trying this code but i find it difficult applying to the plugin i used : [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ibnclaudius/BnPa6/52/)